# Assigning to Pandas DataFrame inside class gives TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing calculations on a dataframe within a class:

the dataframe looks something like this:

```
            JIBA3M  Year Month Day Day_b   MonthBegin
2014-01-01  0.05216 2014    1   1   1   2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-02  0.05216 2014    1   2   1   2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-03  0.05225 2014    1   3   1   2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-04  0.05225 2014    1   4   1   2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-05  0.05225 2014    1   5   1   2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

outside of the class in ipython notebook the following works interchangeably:

```
df['MonthBegin'] = df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day_b']].apply(lambda s : datetime.datetime(*s), axis=1)
and
df['MonthBegin'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.Year, x.Month, 1), axis=1)
```

if I try the code from within the **init** method of the class though the second
way gives error:

```
TypeError: ('integer argument expected, got float', u'occurred at index 2014-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I have checked and the `apply lambda` part gives the expected results if I `debug print` it.
The problem seems to be assigning the apply lambda construct back to the DataFrame.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you're saying if you do this on two lines: x = df[..].apply(..) and df[..] = x, this errors on the assignment/second line?

Comment: yes both methods work interchangebly using ipython notebook running on same versions of packages... All the months dates etc are numpy ints so it is not them causing the problem.  pandas==0.13.1 and numpy==1.8.0 for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ensure these are ints by converting them:

```
df['MonthBegin'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(int(x.Year), int(x.Month), 1), axis=1)
```

or potentially converting each column to ensure it's int64 (and not float):

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(np.int64)
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype(np.int64)
```

Note: it could be there are some NaNs causing this float upcasting, in which case you may have to reconsider your approach (since you won't be able to convert to int!), one option might be to do the string formatting and then apply `to_datetime`:

```
df['Date'] = df.Year + '-' + df.Month + '-' + '01'
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Comment: thanks suggestions worked.  I am confused though checked every single item in df.Month and df.Year and they are all numpy.int32 and there are no NaNs the dtype of the two columns are both dtype('int32').   Surely the lambda construct cannot change the type?

Comment: PS the Month and Year come directly from the index of df:          df['Year'] = df.index.year
df['Month'] = df.index.month

Comment: @Joop that's weird it's int32 (are you on windows 32 bit?), hmmm I guess it upcasts to float if there's a NaT? IIRC the lambda is ensuring it raises if it's not an int (which makes a NaN). I favour the last solution (and not use the lambda or the astype stuff).

Comment: Yes have 32 bit python installs.   Started with that because 2 years ago a lot of the packages still had some holes in them.   Agree that something is upcasting to float, but i cannot seem to recreate it in isolated test code.   Side question:  Is it good idea to move to 64bit python 2.7?  mainly using pandas, numpy, but also sftp etc modules.

Comment: @Joop I guess it's up to you, I heartily recommend using [anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html) nowadays - makes installing and updating packages *significantly* easier/trivial.